# Streaming RTSP to WebRTC using Kurento

Tags: webrtc, rtsp, kurento

I have been testing out Kurento for a while now.
I have gone through one2many sample, and got everything working.

Now I would like to do the same, but have the "presenter" be an RTSP source.

I don't have much experience with RTSP, so I might be missing something. I have looked over several samples and they all use the `PlayerEndpoint`, which receives an `rtsp://...` address.

For my implementation, I would rather the camera access a Kurento URL in order to initiate the RTSP stream.

Since I have very limited experience with RTSP, I'm not sure if this is possible and if it's a common practice.

If not, what are the alternative in a case where I don't know the RTSP URI in advance and don't have a UI to input it at runtime?

Comment: did you find anything to fit your needs?

Answer (score 2):

Follow this [example project](https://github.com/lulop-k/kurento-rtsp2webrtc), you can simply make Kurento streaming RTSP to WebRTC on the fly.

[image]

Comment: Hi, I know I'm late for the party but, have you tried to make this solution work up to this date??

Comment: Hey, does anyone know how to get this solution work if the RTSP camera and the rtsp2webrtc client are on different networks, i.e., behind different NATs?

Comment: can you provide some sample in java?